# Fastest way to copy small - medium chunks of memory in C++

Tags: c++, directshow

I'm copying a byte buffer in a `Directshow` filter into a buffer provided from a `C#` program, the buffer contains a bitmap of the current frame and so varies in size depending on video width and height.

I find smaller videos are retrieving the video frame super fast, however larger videos are taking some time. I'm doing what I think is the simplest way (this doesn't mean I'm right that's why I'm asking).

Please can you tell me if this is the fastest way of copying the memory ? Thanks

C++ code:

```
STDMETHODIMP CSampleGrabber::GetBuffer(byte* pVideoBuffer)
{    
    int p=0;

    while (p< nBufSize) {
        pVideoBuffer[p]=pBufferData[p];
        p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use memcpy or std::copy from the standard library.

Comment: @ronag this should be an answer :)

Comment: You're not going to meet that time by much, I think you have to figure out how to _eliminate_ copies.

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::copy` from the standard library, alternatively you can use `memcpy`, however `std::copy` will be as fast as `memcpy`.

```
std::copy(pVideoBuffer, pVideoBuffer+nBufSize, pBufferData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::copy` or `memcpy` are going to be a fast as they can be.

For processing video frames you want to avoid copying and memory allocations as much as possible.  To that end I would take the following approach.

1. Allocate a pool of video frames equal to the depth of your video processing pipeline.
2. Copy **ONCE** out of your SampleGrabber callback and avoid any further copies.
3. Place your video frame processing on a separate thread or threads to improve performance.

If you are doing any kind of video decoding the memory bandwidth shouldn't be a major issue unless you are running at a very high frame rate or processing very large video (2K or 4K) on a memory constrained system.

If you really need a parallelized memory copy, You can also investigate using Intel's [Thread Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) to create a parallelized task to copy the video frame in blocks.  But, unless your video's are gigantic you might not see a huge performance improvement beyond straight memcpy.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using C++ why not use `std::copy`?

```
std::copy(pBufferData, pBufferData + nBufSize, pVideoBuffer);
```

copy should use `memcopy` or `memmove` which in turn will use fast machine code instruction.

Answer (score 0):

memcpy(pVideoBuffer, pBufferData, nBufSize)

Documentation is here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/

Answer (score 0):

C options: memcpy/memmove

"memcpy is more efficient than memmove." In general, USE memmove only if you have to. USE it when there is a very reasonable chance that the source and destination regions are over-lapping.

Use Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yr1YnOVG-4g Dr. Jerry Cain, (Stanford Intro Systems Lecture - 7) Time: 36:00